# Using fragments for TAB layout, how to use them?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using fragments to get the Tabs style on my app, like seen here:

[Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh8Wh.png)

Already deducted that each tab is a fragment and each one has a layout, but i cant display on each one display what i want. 
Before having the fragments i had a simple activity to display data from a database on a listview, but now i cant get it to work on one of the fragments, with the following code that i used:

```
dal = new DAL(TabListas.this);
        dal.connect(DBAccessMode.READ);

        Cursor cursor = dal.selectALLFromRegSintomas();

        // Find ListView to populate
        ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
        // Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
        RegistosCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new RegistosCursorAdapter(TabListas.this, cursor, 0);
        // Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

**How can i make a use the fragments to display data from db in a listview in one fragment ? What should i change ?**

---

**VerRegsSintomas.java (like mainactivity.java):**

```
    package com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.Activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.CursorAdapter.RegistosCursorAdapter;
import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.R;
import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.TabFragments.PageAdapter;
import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.database.DAL;
import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.database.DBAccessMode;

public class VerRegsSintomas extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private DAL dal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_regs_sintomas);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1a212c")));

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Sintomas"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Listas"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**PageAdapter.java:**

```
 package com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.TabFragments;

/**
 * Created by BugDroid on 07/06/2016.
 */

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabSintomas tab1 = new TabSintomas();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabListas tab2 = new TabListas();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

**TabSintomas.java:**

```
    package com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.TabFragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.R;

public class TabSintomas extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_sintomas, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_Tab_sintomas.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Activities.VerRegistos">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Example](https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/) ,here you can find a TabLayout with the help of Viewpager and custom toolbar and along with this all you can find a navigation drawer over there.